# Elixir plug: register_before_send

Tags: elixir

According to the documentation, `Plug.Conn.register_before_send` registers a callback that is invoked before the request is sent. The following code prints only the "setting up" message but not "cleaning up".

```
defmodule MyRouter do
  use Plug.Router

  # Starts the server
  def start do
    Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http MyRouter, []
  end

  plug :my_handle # custom plug
  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  def my_handle(conn, _opts) do
    Plug.Conn.register_before_send(conn, fn conn -> 
      # Doesn't show up in console.
      IO.puts "== cleaning up =="
      conn
    end)
    # This is printed to the console.
    IO.puts "== setting up =="
    conn
  end

  get "/" do
    send_resp(conn, 200, "world")
  end

  match _ do
    send_resp(conn, 404, "oops")
  end
end
```

Is there anything I missed from docs? What is the setup in order to make this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are right, however you are not using the conn that has the before_send registered (don't forget that variables are immutable in Elixir.)

Change:

```
Plug.Conn.register_before_send(conn, fn conn ->
```

To:

```
conn = Plug.Conn.register_before_send(conn, fn conn ->
```

Or rewrite the function so the conn returned from `register_before_send` is returned:

```
def my_handle(conn, _opts) do
  IO.puts "== setting up =="
  Plug.Conn.register_before_send(conn, fn conn -> 
    # Doesn't show up in console.
    IO.puts "== cleaning up =="
    conn
  end)
end
```